# Is there a command to completely roll back every change made to a Mint system

Tags: linux-mint

I'm looking to roll back my Mint system to the day I installed it. I don't want to keep any files, packages etc. Just start over. Is there a simple way to do this without fully reinstalling Mint? My issue is I don't have the installation media (and don't have a USB/CD writer).

Comment: A $10 USB Flash drive would have capacity to spare for a minimal installation disk.

Comment: Also, this is the purpose of a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Resetter](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/#how-to-install) avilable on the git repository.

```
wget https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/releases/download/v1.1.2-stable/add-apt-key_1.0-0.5_all.deb
wget https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/releases/download/v1.1.2-stable/resetter_1.1.2-stable_all.deb
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi add-apt-key_1.0-0.5_all.deb
sudo gdebi resetter_1.1.2-stable_all.deb
```

> **Officially supported distros [64-bit]**
>
> - Linux Mint 17.3+
>
>   - Ubuntu 14.04+ (ubuntu 17.10 not supported at the moment)
>   - Elementary OS 0.4+
>   - Linux Deepin 15.4+

[omgubuntu : Reset Ubuntu to Default with This New App](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/reset-ubuntu-desktop-default-settings)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to roll back a Linux system such as Mint to the install date unless (1) you fully backed up the system to some sort of media, or (2) installed as a guest VM on a hypervisor and took a snapshot of the VM after installation.